# Installing El Capitan in the same HD of MacBook Air with macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, install, partition, hdmi

I have macOS Sierra 10.12.5 in my MacBook Air, but I suffering Flickering with Samsung Smart TV & Epson Projector. I tested an Old Notebook with Windows 10, works perfectly with my Smart TV.

By mistake, I tried to do an clean installation of the macOS Sierra (because my MacBook comes with El Capitan and it was upgraded), but I had problem and El Capitan was installed instead of.

I tested recent installed El Capitan with my Samsung Smart TV and WOW Zero Flickering, even plugin it for first time!!!, I view a movie without problem. Later I do a clean installation of macOS Sierra, and the flickering began immediately!!!

I want to perform a parallel installation (El Capitan:20GB  and Sierra another Space) in another partition to test EL Capitan without loss my Sierra installation to test my HDMI port.

**NOTE:** *Virtual Machine is not option, because the Thunderbold port for HDMI is managed by the Host (Sierra).*

**Is there a method previously tested to do this?**

**How I get the El Capitan again (I can't get from the App Store)?** We Could not complete your purchase, (Sierra is newer than El Capitan).

Comment: Internet Recovery will do this.  Hold down `Option-Command-R` or `Shift-Option-Command-R`

Comment: It will reinstall the OS that came with your MBA

Comment: You need to start somewhere.  Without El Cap installer, you'll  need it to reinstall it first.  Do a time machine backup, install El Cap, **then** create another partition to install Sierra.  Since you have El Cap, you can download a Sierra installer and then create another partition to install it on.

Comment: I installed again "El Capitan" now I have 10.11.6 version, I want to keep it. But I can't download from App Store Still (https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12) again: **We could not complete your purchase.** with *This version of OS X 10.11 cannot be installed on this computer.*

Comment: El Cap is installed.  You need to download Sierra now per my instructions.  **Don't install it.  Create a USB installer**.  Create a new partition, then install Sierra there.